# Julia ERROR: UndefVarError: σ not defined

Tags: julia, flux-machine-learning

I am running this from julia:

```
W1 = param(rand(3, 5))
b1 = param(rand(3))
layer1(x) = W1 * x .+ b1
W2 = param(rand(2, 3))
b2 = param(rand(2))

layer2(x) = W2 * x .+ b2
model(x) = layer2(σ.(layer1(x)))

model(rand(5))
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: σ not defined
Stacktrace:
[1] model(::Array{Float64,1}) at ./REPL[35]:1
```

I dont understand the error. I am new to julia. Please help me out here. I am following this tutorial: https://fluxml.github.io/Flux.jl/stable/models/basics.html#Taking-Gradients-1

Thank you.

Comment: You forgot to say `using Flux`

Comment: Try adding `using NNlib` in addition to `using Flux`. It is probably a documentation bug

Comment: Flux.lj "uses" NNlib and exports sigma (https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/blob/1baa7227e3a4f835133e41db51bf51a89ec91a10/src/Flux.jl#L16)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked by adding:  `using Flux`

Comment: @oakad could you please post your comment as an answer so this question can be marked as solved? (I would rather use `using Foo: bar, baz` explicitly.)

Comment: I'm new to Julia. Can someone explain why "using Flux" solves the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can check the comments. This can be solved by adding `using Flux` or `using Foo:bar, baz` before the the given code.

Comment: Why "using Flux" solves the error?